# python: union keys from multiple dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, reduce

I have 5 dictionaries and I want a union of their keys.

```
alldict =  [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5]
```

I tried

```
allkey = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x.keys()).union(y.keys()), alldict)
```

but it gave me an error

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Am I doing it wrong ?  I using normal forloop but I wonder why the above code didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your solution works for the first two elements in the list, but then `dict1` and `dict2` got reduced into a set and that set is put into your lambda as the `x`. So now `x` does not have the method `keys()` anymore.

The solution is to make x be a set from the very beginning by initializing the reduction with an empty set (which happens to be the neutral element of the union).

Try it with an initializer:

```
allkey = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y.keys()), alldict, set())
```

An alternative without any lambdas would be:

```
allkey = reduce(set.union, map(set, map(dict.keys, alldict)))
```

Comment: Almost... try set() as the initializer

Comment: Or: `allkey = reduce(set.union, (set(d.keys()) for d in alldict))`

Answer (score 74):

I think @chuck already answered the question why it doesn't work, but a simpler way to do this would be to remember that the `union` method can take multiple arguments:

```
allkey = set().union(*alldict)
```

does what you want without any loops or lambdas.

Answer (score 5):

A simple strategy for non-functional neurons (pun intended):

```
allkey = []

for dictio in alldict:
    for key in dictio:
        allkey.append(key)

allkey = set(allkey)
```

We can convert this code to a much sorter form using set comprehensions:

```
allkey = {key for dictio in alldict for key in dictio}
```

This one-liner is still very readable in comparison with the conventional for loop.
The key to convert a nested loop to a list or set comprehension is to write the inner loop (the one that varies faster in the nested loop) as the last index (that is,  `for key in dictio`).

Comment: @BjörnPollex You are right, the (set) comprehension successfully competes with functional alternatives both in readability and conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

```
set().union(dict1.keys(),dict2.keys()...)
```

I tried the list and it didnt work so just putting it up here for anyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to union keys of 2 dicts you could use operator `|`.

Quote from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union):

> Return a new set with elements from the set and all others.

Example:

```py
all_keys = dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more way, 'cause what the hay:

```
a={}; [ a.update(b) for b in alldict ] and a.keys()
```

or the slightly-more-mysterious

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a.update(b) or a, alldict, {}).keys()
```

(I'm bummed that there's no built-in function equivalent to

```
def f(a,b):
   r = {}
   r.update(a)
   r.update(b)
   return r
```

is there?)

Comment: Try: `def f(a, b): return dict(a.items() + b.items())`