# Fast way to iterate over three dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dictionary

I am dealing with very large three dictionaries which looks like this:

```
dict_a = { ( 't','e' ) : [0.5,0.1,0.6],  ( 'a','b' ) : [0.2,0.3,0.9] }

dict_b = { ( 'a','b' ) : [0.1,0.5,0.3] , ( 't','e' ) : [0.6,0.1,0.6] }

dict_c = { ( 'a','b' ) : [0.1,0.5,0.3] , ( 't','e' ) : [0.6,0.5,0.6] }
```

I am looking for the output like this :

```
    name    first_value       second_value  third_value

0   (t, e)  [0.5, 0.1, 0.6] [0.6, 0.1, 0.6] [0.6, 0.5, 0.6]
1   (a, b)  [0.2, 0.3, 0.9] [0.1, 0.5, 0.3] [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]
```

What I've tried is :

```
final_dict = {'name': [] , 'first_value' : [] ,'second_value': [] , 'third_value': [] }

for a,b in dict_a.items():
    for c,d in dict_b.items():
        for e,f in dict_c.items():
            if a==c==e:
                final_dict['name'].append(a)
                final_dict['first_value'].append(b)
                final_dict['second_value'].append(d)
                final_dict['third_value'].append(f)
```

Which is really not efficient and optimize way to do this task. I was thinking to use pandas.

How can I do this task in minimal time complexity?

Thank you !

Comment: This gets you all the keys from all the dicts, so you only need one loop. O(n) + O(n) = O(n) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242311/python-union-keys-from-multiple-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict_a, dict_b, dict_c], index = ['first_value', 
'second_value', 'third_value']).T
df['names'] = df.index
df.index = [0, 1]
print(df)
```

Output:-

```
       first_value     second_value      third_value   names
0  [0.2, 0.3, 0.9]  [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]  [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]  (a, b)
1  [0.5, 0.1, 0.6]  [0.6, 0.1, 0.6]  [0.6, 0.5, 0.6]  (t, e)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because these are dictionaries, you only need to iterate over one. You can use the key to get the corresponding value from the others.

Example:

```
for key, value in dict_a.items():
        final_dict['name'].append(key)
        final_dict['first_value'].append(value)
        final_dict['second_value'].append(dict_b[key])
        final_dict['third_value'].append(dict_c[key])
```

Comment: For readability, I might just use `for key_in dict_a`. Then the `final_dict` assignments (aside from the first) can all be written uniformly as `final_dict['...'].append(...[key])`.

Comment: (Might be good to confirm, too, that all three dictionaries have the same set of keys.)

Comment: I was thinking set union of the keys, then iterate over keys to build the output -- just in case some dict happens to be missing some entry.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
pd.DataFrame({i:d for i,d in enumerate([dict_a,dict_b,dict_c])} )
```

Output:

```
                   0                1                2
a b  [0.2, 0.3, 0.9]  [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]  [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]
t e  [0.5, 0.1, 0.6]  [0.6, 0.1, 0.6]  [0.6, 0.5, 0.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in [dict_a,dict_b,dict_c]],axis=1)
Out[332]: 
                   0                1                2
a b  [0.2, 0.3, 0.9]  [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]  [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]
t e  [0.5, 0.1, 0.6]  [0.6, 0.1, 0.6]  [0.6, 0.5, 0.6]
```